# i am having a lot of difficulties with baking textures

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have been modelling a quite complex character with a lot of nodes in its shader editor, I want to bake these textures but they keep failing, not showing up, or working as intended.

[image]

This image I baked it but its not working, I'm still unsure how to do it, all the tutorials i have seen have not been helping

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you create a new UVMap for the baked textures?

Comment: a uv map, not for his, i just added image texture, went on diffuse and click bake, the tutoriel never said anything about uv map could you explain how or why its important?

Comment: UV are some of the basic principles in computer graphics, I cannot explain them in a short answer but the web is full of good tutorials about them. You absolutely need to familiarize with UVs before baking textures.